# Vec::dedup does not work — how do I deduplicate a vector of strings?

Tags: string, vector, rust

I've parsed a file, split the string by lines and want to leave only unique elements in each vector. I expect `vec.dedup()` to work like this:

```
let mut vec = vec!["a", "b", "a"];
vec.dedup();
assert_eq!(vec, ["a", "b"]);
```

But it fails:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `["a", "b", "a"]`,
 right: `["a", "b"]`', src/main.rs:4:4
```

How can I remove duplicates?

Comment: The documentation states that dedup only removes consecutive duplicates. Maybe sort first? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As documented, [`Vec#dedup`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup) only removes **consecutive** elements from a vector (it is much cheaper than a full deduplication). It would work fine if the vector was `vec!["a", "a", "b"]`, for example.

Of course, there are multiple potential solutions.

In order to obtain a vector with all duplicates removed while retaining the original order of the elements, the `itertools` crate provides a [`unique`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.4/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique) adaptor.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let v = vec!["b", "a", "b"];
let v: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().unique().collect();
assert_eq!(v, ["b", "a"]);
```

If element order is not important, you may sort the elements first and then call dedupe.

```
let mut v = vec!["a", "b", "a"];
v.sort_unstable();
v.dedup();
assert_eq!(v, ["a", "b"]);
```

If fast element lookup is important, you may also consider using a set type instead, such as `HashSet`.

```
let v: HashSet<_> = ["a", "b", "a"].iter().cloned().collect();
let v2: HashSet<_> = ["b", "a"].iter().cloned().collect();
assert_eq!(v, v2);
```

Comment: I just did sort(), to get same values into consecutive positions, then dedup().

Answer (score 21):

The other answer points out that a `HashSet` is a better choice for a collection without duplicates, which I agree with. This shows how to directly deduplicate a `Vec` using that property of `HashMap` and without sorting the `Vec` first to use `std::vec::Vec::dedup`.

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn dedup<T: Eq + Hash + Copy>(v: &mut Vec<T>) { // note the Copy constraint
    let mut uniques = HashSet::new();
    v.retain(|e| uniques.insert(*e));
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec!["a", "b", "a"];
    dedup(&mut v);

    assert_eq!(&v, &vec!["a", "b"]);
}
```

This is a fast (O(n)) solution, but creating the `HashSet` requires some extra memory.

Comment: In a way, this should be an inline form of the `unique` adaptor.