# How can I dedupe an immutable list of Cloneable objects with only a single clone of each item?

Tags: rust, duplicates

Thanks to another SO answer, I successfully wrote a function that deduplicates a Vec. However, it does two clones of each item. I want to be able to do this with a single clone.

Here is the gist of what I am doing.

- The incoming Vec is not mutable.
- The output list must preserve order of retained items.
- The type of item is Clone, not Copy.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn distinct_values<T: Clone + Hash + Eq>(list: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut set: HashSet<T> = HashSet::with_capacity(list.len());
    let deduped: Vec<T> = list
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|item| set.insert(item.clone()))
        .collect();
    deduped
}
```

The other question that I studied was:
[Vec::dedup does not work — how do I deduplicate a vector of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636618/vecdedup-does-not-work-how-do-i-deduplicate-a-vector-of-strings/47636725#47636725)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the items in the hashset: references would be enough.

Note also that you should prefer passing `&[T]` instead of `&Vec<T>` as argument as it covers more cases. So I'd change your code to

```rust
pub fn distinct_values<T: Clone + Hash + Eq>(list: &[T]) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut set: HashSet<&T> = HashSet::with_capacity(list.len());
    list
        .iter()
        .filter(|item| set.insert(item))
        .cloned()
        .collect()
}
```

Not only do you avoid to clone all items twice, you don't clone at all the items you don't keep.

Comment: Whoa! Very nice. Even better than what I asked for!

Comment: Just verified in my unit tests. Works like a charm.